User/Device Identity for enterprise chrome extension -Via- Chrome Browser Cloud Management
We are building an enterprise browser extension and it will be deployed via Chrome Browser Cloud Management on Windows/MacOS/Linux Devices.
How can we gather the user identity or the device identifier, such that the extension can use it for further communication with our API services?
In case of managed devices, where the extension is deployed via GPO, we have the option to populate the registry/managed policy and retrieve the information via managed storage. However, in case of Chrome Browser Cloud Management, how can we get this information on the extension.
The extension API "chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes" seems to be way, but it says it is only available for ChromeOS, does it work for Windows and other devices?
We have tried:

Using chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes, however, it didn't work, We are not fully sure if there was an issue in our code or the API is not available on Windows/MacOS/Linux as the web page says its only available on ChromeOS.

Using Custom configurations on the Chrome Browser Cloud Management to add the relevant properties inside the managed storage, but it threw the error "The following policies are invalid: 3rdparty".


